# ImagesLoaded and Masonry in the second AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, masonry

I load the page content with an ajax call and init the masonry gallery with the following code with no problem.

```
$(".masonry-wrapper").imagesLoaded( container, function() {

    setTimeout(function () {
        msnry = new Masonry( container, {gutter: 6} );
    }, 100);

});
```

But when I do a second ajax call, refresh the gallery content, the gallery images overlap. I guess imagesLoaded doesn't work in that case.

- I actually put setTimeout to avoid this but didn't work.
- I tried setInterval, it worked but I don't want such a harsh method to be the solution.

What would you offer for the second AJAX call?
Thanks by now.

(I know that putting gallery content with AJAX calls is not a beautiful way but the project requires this.)

Comment: You need a function -- example (function checkimgs() { $(".masonry-wrapper").imagesLoaded().done( function( container ) {  msnry = new Masonry( container, {gutter: 6} ); })})  and run the function like so (checkimgs()) in your ajax success call -- what you have in your question runs only once, hence why if you put interval it just keeps on repeating itself so you think its working but its not -- anyway check the docs also fo imagesloaded under Jquery Deferred -- http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/

Comment: .done() solved my problem, thank you. Why didn't you write as an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: ok, ill put it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

You need a function e.g

```
function checkimgs() { $(".masonry-wrapper").imagesLoaded().done( function( container ) { msnry = new Masonry( container, {gutter: 6} ); })}
```

and run the function like so `checkimgs()` in your ajax success call